# Object.values() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

The prototypeJS library has a method Object.values() which returns an array of values in an object.

EG:

```
 var myObj = {
   "key1" : "val1"
   "key2" : "val2"
 }
 Object.values(myObj) //returns ["val1", "val2"]
```

is there a jQuery method that does the same thing?

Comment: No, there is not. It's easy to create though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6, you can do the following:

```
Object.values = x =>
        Object.keys(x).reduce((y, z) =>
            y.push(x[z]) && y, []);
```

This simply returns an array containing the object's values. No need for JQuery, _ or anything else.

---

**note:** `Object.values()` is currently in draft for ES7

Using babel, installing

- babel-preset-es2017
- babel-plugin-transform-runtime

gives support for `Object.values/Object.entries` as well as other `ES2017` functionality.

As per recommendation by the modules, configure the `.babelrc` file with the following:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "presets": ["es2017"]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I don't think there's a method that does it directly, but you can use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
$.map(myObj, function(val, key) { return val; }); //returns ["val1", "val2"]
```

(Note though that if the callback returns `null` or `undefined` for a given property that item will not be included in the new array, so if your object might have properties with those values you'll have to do it another way. It's pretty easy to code from scratch though, with a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.)

Comment: Should be `... function(key, val) ...` instead of `... function(val, key) ...`

Comment: @AndreiStalbe - No it shouldn't. Check [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

Answer (score 5):

prototypejs' `values` method extends JavaScript's builtin `Object` object. There's nothing stopping you from doing the same:

```
Object.values = function(object) {
  var values = [];
  for(var property in object) {
    values.push(object[property]);
  }
  return values;
}


var foo = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
console.log(Object.values(foo));
// [1, 2, 3]
```

Alternatively, you can add the method described above to the jQuery object if you'd rather not tamper with `Object`:

```
$.values = function() { ... }
```

Comment: awesome! this is perfect! thank you so much! It's perfect since you don't need to add a whole new library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#values) has the `_.values` method:
`_.values({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3}); => [1, 2, 3]`

This library augments JQuery very well - as well as working wonderfully in prototypejs.